# Call controller function within another controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to call a function `Commanfuntion` in controller `Return_test` which is located in the `Assign_test` controller.

Example:

```
class Assign_test extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function Commanfuntion()
    {
     //code
    }
}
```

---

```
class Return_test extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function Return()
    {
     //here I want to call Commanfuntion located in class Assign_test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Codeigniter follows the MVC pattern you can't call a controller function in another controller. However you can do this by using a function helper and call the function from function helper in any controller.